# What would be the adjectivalform of something related to "sound"?

Tags: adjectives, derivational-morphology

An example sentence would be:

There is some music that is the ____ equivalent of poetry to me.

It's not quite "musical" since I want the word to be more closely related to sound whereas music is a kind of sound. I thought of "sonorous," given its Latin root, but the definition of that is "(of a person's voice or other sound) imposingly deep and full" and I'm looking for a word that is more neutral. I also thought of "phonetic" but that is more closely related to speech.

Comment: ...Perhaps  audio?

Comment: *auditory* or *aural*

Answer (score 7):

I think ***aural*** is commonly used in sentences like your example. Technically it's "related to hearing" but I think it gets your point across better than "related to sound," which is "sonic."

**aural** from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aural)

> of or relating to the ear or to the sense of hearing

Comment: I added a dictionary definition and a link to make your answer stronger.  But it is your answer, and you can edit my edit or rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: @ab2 Definitely an improvement; thanks!